# height 100% and "bottom" not working together

Tags: css

I have some divs set to 100% height (of the page), and body and Html set to 100% height too. Straight forward, looks fine. Next I'm trying to add some elements that are positioned to the bottom, but instead of reaching the bottom of the div which is visibly at the bottom of the screen, it's sitting as if the "bottom" is where the bottom would be if there was no "height:100%;"...

Basically, height:100% is setting the height of the div, but not setting where the bottom is. If that makes any sense (it doesn't to me).

Live example here: http://careers.dept.shef.ac.uk/MOOCs/STAR

The white circle/arrow thing should be just close to the bottom of the screen, but instead it's positioned off the bottom of the dark blue box, where the bottom of the light blue would be without the height css. I'm baffled.

Anyone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this on the element which you need to be placed at the bottom:

```
element {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```

and apply this to the parent element:

```
element{
position: relative;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LqVur/)

Comment: Got it just using left:45%

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a margin to it and it will push it down without effecting the centering as `position:absolute;` does.

```
.arrow {
    width: 122px;
    height: 121px;
    background-image: url('arrows.png');
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 1s ease 2s;
    position: relative;
    margin: 300px auto;
}
```

I added 300px to the margin and it looked great.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I was trying that although it felt like a bit of a messy solution as it isn't as responsive. It would mean getting the perfect margin to make sure it didn't get lost on any windows with reduced height.

Comment: @SteveMcCarthy You can give it a % and it will resize on screen height.